# How to fix Lsyncd Active (exited) Error?

Tags: rsync

Installed lsyncd on Ubuntu 20.04

create lsyncd.conf.lua

```
settings = {
    logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status"
}

sync {
    default.rsyncssh,
    source = "/var/www/",
    host = "1.1.1.1",
    targetdir = "/var/vidsg"
}
```

systemctl status lsyncd get me this

```
● lsyncd.service - LSB: lsyncd daemon init script
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/lsyncd; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2021-08-15 00:04:19 CEST; 11min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 3460 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/lsyncd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

systemd[1]: Starting LSB: lsyncd daemon init script...
lsyncd[3460]:  * Starting synchronization daemon lsyncd
lsyncd[3466]: Error: Do not use settings = { ... }
lsyncd[3466]:       please use settings{ ... } (without the equal sign)
lsyncd[3460]:    ...fail!
systemd[1]: Started LSB: lsyncd daemon init script.
```

And if I run journalctl I see this :

```
Aug 14 22:36:10 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1004057]:    ...fail!
Aug 14 22:36:10 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: lsyncd daemon init script.
Aug 14 22:37:28 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: lsyncd daemon init script...
Aug 14 22:37:28 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1004328]:  * Stopping synchronization daemon lsyncd
Aug 14 22:37:28 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1004328]:    ...done.
Aug 14 22:37:28 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: lsyncd.service: Succeeded.
Aug 14 22:37:28 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: lsyncd daemon init script.
Aug 14 22:37:28 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: lsyncd daemon init script...
Aug 14 22:37:28 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1004345]:  * Starting synchronization daemon lsyncd
Aug 14 22:37:28 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1004350]: Error: Do not use settings = { ... }
Aug 14 22:37:28 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1004350]:       please use settings{ ... } (without the equal sign)
Aug 14 22:37:28 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1004345]:    ...fail!
Aug 14 22:37:28 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: lsyncd daemon init script.
Aug 14 22:39:28 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: lsyncd daemon init script...
Aug 14 22:39:28 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1004484]:  * Stopping synchronization daemon lsyncd
Aug 14 22:39:28 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1004484]:    ...done.
Aug 14 22:39:28 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: lsyncd.service: Succeeded.
Aug 14 22:39:28 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: lsyncd daemon init script.
Aug 14 22:39:28 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: lsyncd daemon init script...
Aug 14 22:39:28 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1004499]:  * Starting synchronization daemon lsyncd
Aug 14 22:39:28 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1004505]: Error: Do not use settings = { ... }
Aug 14 22:39:28 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1004505]:       please use settings{ ... } (without the equal sign)
Aug 14 22:39:28 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1004499]:    ...fail!
Aug 14 22:39:28 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: lsyncd daemon init script.
Aug 14 22:57:10 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: lsyncd daemon init script...
Aug 14 22:57:10 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1005037]:  * Stopping synchronization daemon lsyncd
Aug 14 22:57:10 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1005037]:    ...done.
Aug 14 22:57:10 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: lsyncd.service: Succeeded.
Aug 14 22:57:10 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: lsyncd daemon init script.
Aug 14 22:57:10 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: lsyncd daemon init script...
Aug 14 22:57:10 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1005055]:  * Starting synchronization daemon lsyncd
Aug 14 22:57:10 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1005060]: Error: Do not use settings = { ... }
Aug 14 22:57:10 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1005060]:       please use settings{ ... } (without the equal sign)
Aug 14 22:57:10 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1005055]:    ...fail!
Aug 14 22:57:10 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: lsyncd daemon init script.
Aug 14 22:59:13 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: lsyncd daemon init script...
Aug 14 22:59:13 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1005114]:  * Stopping synchronization daemon lsyncd
Aug 14 22:59:13 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1005114]:    ...done.
Aug 14 22:59:13 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: lsyncd.service: Succeeded.
Aug 14 22:59:13 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: lsyncd daemon init script.
Aug 14 22:59:13 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: lsyncd daemon init script...
Aug 14 22:59:13 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1005132]:  * Starting synchronization daemon lsyncd
Aug 14 22:59:13 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1005139]: Error: Do not use settings = { ... }
Aug 14 22:59:13 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1005139]:       please use settings{ ... } (without the equal sign)
Aug 14 22:59:13 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1005132]:    ...fail!
Aug 14 22:59:13 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: lsyncd daemon init script.
Aug 14 22:59:58 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: lsyncd daemon init script...
Aug 14 22:59:58 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1005250]:  * Stopping synchronization daemon lsyncd
Aug 14 22:59:58 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[1005250]:    ...done.
Aug 14 22:59:58 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: lsyncd.service: Succeeded.
Aug 14 22:59:58 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: lsyncd daemon init script.
-- Reboot --
Aug 14 23:00:24 vmi098767.myserver.net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: lsyncd daemon init script...
Aug 14 23:00:25 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[437]:  * Starting synchronization daemon lsyncd
Aug 14 23:00:25 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[453]: Error: Do not use settings = { ... }
Aug 14 23:00:25 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[453]:       please use settings{ ... } (without the equal sign)
Aug 14 23:00:25 vmi098767.myserver.net lsyncd[437]:    ...fail!
```

How to fix this.

Comment: It *sounds* like it's just telling you to use `settings {` rather than `settings = {` in the config file (the same syntax as you appear to have used for `sync`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error itself is showing the solution.

lsyncd[3466]: Error: Do not use settings = { ... }
lsyncd[3466]:       please use settings{ ... } (without the equal sign)

Your configuration file begins with
settings = {

Instead it should be,
settings {